# How to edit / change default datatable pages message

Tags: datatables

I have a datatable, and I would like to change the default message:

`Showing 21 to 30 of 57 entries`

To:

`Showing 21 to 30 of 57 items` (or whatever)

I found this in the [official doc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language)

So basically I have to change:

```
"info":           "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
"infoEmpty":      "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
```

...

To:

```
"info":           "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ items",
"infoEmpty":      "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 items",
...
```

But I don't know how to hook it up all together.

Is there any possibility to do that without using any additional plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example - no additional plugins are needed:

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "language": {
    "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ items",
    "infoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 items",
    "infoFiltered":   "(filtered from _MAX_ total items)"
  }
} );
```

In the above example I also added a third change, in case you want to handle all examples of "entries" to "items".

---

Some background notes:

These phrases are all part of the [`language`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) option that you referenced.

Generally, this option is used to support changing all phrases to a language other than English - either inline or [via a URL](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/).

But you can use the option to modify the default English phrases also.